# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'txt' of undefined

Tags: 2013, error, pnp-js-core, pnpjs

I am new to PnP JS and I want to try it.

Part my code:

```
import pnp from "sp-pnp-js";
...
pnp.sp.web.select('Title').get()
 .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

But I got an error in console:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
>   position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at core.js:34

[image]

Comment: Error in question happens because JSON.parse() function is getting XML formatted string instead of JSON formatted string.

Comment: @SlavenSemper, yeah, I understand that. But what to do?

Comment: Can you control request `Accept` header? It should contain application/json.

Comment: @SlavenSemper, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **configure** to:

> Sets custom options for current object and all derived objects accessible via chaining.

You can read more about it and find some good examples in below **official documentation**:

[PnP JS - public methods - configure](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/blob/dev/packages/odata/docs/queryable.md#configure).